# Button to randomize pictures won't work the second time

Tags: javascript

```
var fnr = function (a,b) {
// random integer on closed interval
var y = a + Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random());
return y
}


var foo;
var myTimer;

function toRandom() {
    var x = fnr(0, PICTURES.length - 1);
    var y = SERVER + FOLDER + PICTURES[x] + SUFFIX;
    document.getElementById("img").src = y;
    document.getElementById("filename").value = PICTURES[x].toUpperCase();
}

function toRandomize() {
    if(!foo) {
        foo = true;
        document.getElementById("random").value =  "stop shuffle";
        myTimer = setInterval("toRandom()", 600);
    } else {
        foo = false;
        document.getElementById("random").value =  "start shuffle";
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
}       

window.onload = function () {       
   document.getElementById("random").onclick = toRandomize;         
 }


// button in the body of the HTML portion of my code
<input id="random" type="button" value="start shuffle">
```

I have a button to randomize photos, but it won't work the second time. Do you guys have any insight in reading the code? I know fnr stands for first-non-repeating, but I'm not too familiar with how to "reset it," or if it requires a reset to get it to work again. I have the same setup for other functions and they work fine.

It's cut so it will only show the parts relevant to the question. I apologize if it's confusing.

Comment: @procrastinator, is that needed? The button itself works fine. I have the same setup for other functions like slideshow.

Comment: create a test case on jsfiddle where you isolate the problem and post the link to the test case, we are not fortune tellers,we cant guess what the problem is : jsfiddle.net. Want an answer ?give us more code.

Comment: Alright, sorry guys. I just thought that wasn't needed since it does randomize the first time, but just not after I try it a second time in the same session. I thought the issue only lied within the random function. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the fnr function was made by my professor. Adding it above!

Comment: Looks ok at first glance, have you tried to put some alerts or console logs into your functions?

Comment: You could check `y` for example. I mean, is the URL always right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/l33tspeak/yJ2RS/

Unfortunately, the pictures don't display but here it is. It is very messy since I have so many JS files :/. This whole file is rather messy, we are trying to focus on JS even though things could be done in a much easier manner with JQuery

Comment: My code is intertwined with other functions and whatnot. I think I've figured it out. Sorry for the trouble haha